# jQuery: Change Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I've followed the tutorial on this link: http://trulycode.com/bytes/easy-countdown-to-date-with-javascript-jquery/

How I can change date format

```
$("#countdown").countdown({
  date: "8 September 2020 09:00:00",
  format: "on" 
});
```

from:

```
date: "8 September 2020 09:00:00",
```

to:

```
date: "2020-9-8 09:00:00",
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried changing the behavior of the "format" option?  If not, I suggest putting this in a fiddle and take a few whacks at it there.

Comment: After reading the code in the link, it seems you can change that date string to format that is readable by ``Date.parse``. So yeah, ``"2020-9-8 09:00:00"`` should work with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it and then display however you want:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse("8 September 2020 09:00:00"))
var newFormat = '' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + ' ' + date.toTimeString().slice(0,8)
// -> 2020-9-8 09:00:00
```

Note that `getMonth()` indexes from 0, so September will be 8, which is why you have to add 1 if you want it to be 9.

Comment: I am new in Jquery. Where I do put the code? Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bghndf30/. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the code seems to work fine when you just put `2020-9-8 09:00:00` in place of `8 September 2020 09:00:00`.  It's just calling `Date.parse()` (line 8) anyway, so either is fine.

Comment: Also I should mention that code is quite bad and way overcomplicated.  I'd recommend looking for another tutorial to learn from.

Comment: Thanks but when I do this I get "NaN-NaN-NaN"